# Multi-Dimensional array count in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimentional array set up as follows

```
array() {
    ["type1"] =>
    array() {
        ["ticket1"] =>
        array(9) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
        ["ticket2"] =>
        array(10) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
        ["ticket3"] =>
        array(9) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
    }
    ["type2"] =>
    array() {
        ["ticket1"] =>
        array(9) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
        ["ticket2"] =>
        array(10) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
        ["ticket3"] =>
        array(9) { 
           // ticket details here
        }
    }
}
```

etc.

I am trying to get a count of the total number of tickets in the array (number of second level items), but the number of types is variable as are the number of fields that each ticket has, so I cannot use COUNT_RECURSIVE and maths to get the number.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha a count addition inside a loop (whichever may be best) may be better, since you dont have to iterate everything.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $type) {
    $count+= count($type);
}
```

Answer (score 71):

A bit late but this is a clean way to write it.

```
$totalTickets = array_sum(array_map("count", $tickets));
```

Assuming `$tickets` is your multi-dimensional array.

I've expanded the code to give an explained example because [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) might be new to some

```
$tickets = array(
    "type1" => array(
        "ticket1" => array(),
        "ticket2" => array(),
        "ticket3" => array(),
    ),
    "type2" => array(
        "ticket4" => array(),
        "ticket5" => array(),
        "ticket6" => array(),
        "ticket7" => array(),
    ),
    "type3" => array(
        "ticket8" => array()
    )
);

// First we map count over every first level item in the array
// giving us the total number of tickets for each type.
$typeTotals = array_map("count", $tickets);

// print_r($typeTotals);
// $type_totals --> Array (
//                       [type1] => 3,
//                       [type2] => 4,
//                       [type3] => 1 
//                  )

//Then we sum the values of each of these
$totalTickets = array_sum($typeTotals);

print($totalTickets);
// $totalTickets --> 8
```

So because we don't care about the intermediate result of each type we can feed the result into [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
$totalTickets = array_sum(array_map("count", $tickets));
```

Answer (score 32):

Use **Count Recursive** and subtract the **First level count**, like this:

```
count($mainArr, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($mainArr);
```

If your array has +3 levels, just add [?] keys:

```
count($mainArr[1], COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($mainArr[1]);
```

Comment: what if i have 4 dimensional array?

Comment: Excellent! @nashwa, recursive will count every element IIRC, no matter how deep

Comment: For me `count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE)` was sufficient but great answer as it allows more depth

Answer (score 3):

:)

```
$test = array (
    array (
        'test','test','test'
    ),
    array (
    'test','test'
    ),
    array (
        array (
        'test'
        ),
        array (
        'test','test','test','test'
        )
    )
 );
 echo "  array count ". count($test[0]) ." <br /> ";
 echo "  array count ". count($test[1]) ." <br /> ";
 echo "  array count ". count($test[2]) ." <br /> ";
 echo "  array count ". count($test[2],1) ." <br /> ";
 echo "  array count ". (count($test[2],1) - count($test[2])) ." <br /> "; // all child num - parent num
 echo "  array count ". count($test[2][1]) ." <br /> ";
```

output:

array count 3

array count 2

array count 2

array count 7

array count 5

array count 4

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is one simple foreach loop:

```php
$count = 0;
foreach( $tickets as $ticketType){
    $count += count( $ticketType);
}
```

Comment: This should work, but your variable naming is really confusing (confused?)

Comment: @FrostyZ I had misspell there, fixed, I've also prefixed `$type` so it'll be clearer what's in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `array_walk_recursive()`

```
$totalTickets = 0;

array_walk_recursive($tickets, function($item) use (&$totalTickets) {
    $totalTickets++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To count total number of Ticket, this bellow code will help you for PHP.

```
foreach($mainArray as $Array){
    foreach($Array as $perTicke){
        $count++;
    }
}
$total_ticket = $count;
```

Comment: Don't do a inner foreach loop just to obtain a count of elements.