# How to count the inner array count too

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like as

```
$arr[0] = 'summary';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'address1';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'address2';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'country';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'city';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'pincode';
$arr[1]['contact'][] = 'phone_no';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'address1';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'address2';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'country';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'city';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'pincode';
$arr[2]['work'][] = 'phone_no';
```

Using `count($arr)` it returns `3` but I also need to count inner array values so it will return `13`

What I've tried so far is

```
function getCount($arr,$count = 0) {

    foreach ($arr as $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $count;
            getCount($value,$count);
        }
        $count = $count+1;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo getCount($arr);
```

But its not working as expected

Comment: If you wish to count the values in the inner arrays as well(depth doesn't matter) you can pass in a second parameter to `count` as `count($your_array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)`. Potentially if you want to count only the inner values of the array you can subtract the normal count from the recursive count.

Comment: @Andrew this will return `17`

Comment: Check this [multidimensional array count][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062770/multi-dimensional-array-count-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try this

```
function getCount($arr, $count = 0) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $count = getCount($value, $count);
        } else {
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo getCount($arr);
```

What you were doing over here is that you were not storing the value within any variable and that is making an issues with your code as you were on the perfect way

Answer (score 7):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` for this. This may help -

```
$tot = 0;
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($x) use(&$tot) {
    $tot++;
});
```

But It is a recursive function so you need to be careful about that.

In that `getCount()` method you are not storing the count of the array anywhere. So for every call `$count` is incremented by `1` only.

[DEMO](https://eval.in/417705)

Comment: But where I'm wrong within my code in `foreach` loop because I might have nested array too this one already done. Anyway thanks

Comment: To fix your original function, I think you would either need to do `$count = getCount($value,$count);` or pass `$count` by reference.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to count only the first two levels, you can do a simple foreach, no need to use a recursive function!:

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $bigArray as $smallArray ){
    if( is_array( $smallArray ) )
          $count += count( $smallArray );
    else
          $count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am naive in my approach, but I simply use the `sizeof()` function. The function's documentation shows that it can take a second argument `1` to tell the function to recursively count multidimensional arrays.

So, to get the 'count' you could simply write `sizeof($arr, 1);` and it should return 13.

I recognize the value of writing your own function, but doesn't this built-in PHP method solve the problem quite succinctly?