# Count number of items into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [Europa] => Array
        (
            [country] => France
            [capital] => Paris
        ),
        (
            [country] => Spain
            [capital] => Madrid
        )
    [Asia] => Array
        (
            [country] => Russia
            [capital] => Moscow
        )
)
```

How can I count to number of item containing in `Asia` or Europa`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-Dimensional array count in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062770/multi-dimensional-array-count-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping and count item into a multidimensional array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679649/looping-and-count-item-into-a-multidimensional-array-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
  $myArray= [
    'Europa' => [
            'country' => France
            'capital' => Paris
        ],
        [
            'country' => Spain
            'capital' => Madrid
        ],
    'Asia' => [
            'country' => Russia
            'capital' => Moscow
        ],
  ];
```

you could use count() based on index

```
$numEuropa = count($myArray['Europa']);
$numAsia = count($myArray['Asia']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) in [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as:

```
$cnts = array_map("count", $array);
```

Or with loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
    echo $key . " count is: " . count($value);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/98oYk)