# Looping and count item into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [USA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Apple
                    [Item] => Phones and Computers
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => McDonalds
                    [Item] => Food
                )

        )
    [China] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Lenovo
                    [Item] => Computers
                )
        )
)
```

I would like to loop into it and echo the `count` of items for each country (USA and China).

So my try was this one:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo count($arr[$value]);
    echo '<br />';

    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        echo $value." -> ".$subvalue['Name']." make ".$subvalue['Item']."<br />";    
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `echo count($newArr[$value]);` just `echo count($value);`. And you can not echo `$value` in the second loop as it is array and not a string

Comment: @dWinder $key should be outputted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
foreach ($arr as $country => $companies) {
    echo $country . " has " . count($companies) . " item <br />";

    foreach ($companies as $k => $company) {
        echo $company['Name'] . " make " . $company['Item']."<br />";    
    }
}
```

Keep your variable with meaningful name can make life much easier